# open two materialize modals successively in Angular

Tags: angular, materialize, angular2-materialize

I need to open a modal showing pending transaction once the user clicks send transaction, and once the transaction becomes complete I need to display the transaction successful component.
Transaction pending modal works fine but when it changes to transaction successful I just get a black overlay.

I have written both as separate components

```
<div *ngIf="txnStatus=='pending'">
    <transaction-pending></transaction-pending>
</div>
<div *ngIf="txnStatus=='success'">
    <bought-successfully [transaction]="transaction"></bought-successfully>
</div>
```

In transaction-pending.component.ts

```
 ngOnInit() {
    $('#txn-pending1').modal();  
    $('#txn-pending1').modal('open');
    console.log("transaction pending component loaded");
  }
 ngOnDestroy() {
    console.log("closing pending modal");
    $('#txn-pending1').modal('close');
  }
```

In bought-successfully.component.ts

```
 ngOnInit() {
    console.log("opening the txn success modal");
    $('#txn-bought').modal(); 
    $('#txn-bought').modal('open');            
    console.log("transaction recieved to bought successfully component ",this.transaction);
  }

  ngOnDestroy(){
    console.log("closing the success modal");
    $('#txn-bought').modal('close');
  }
```

This component is being called on success as I can see the logs getting printed in the console, but the modal doesn't appear, only a dark overlay appears.

Versions

1."angular2-materialize": "^15.1.10",
2."materialize-css": "^0.100.2",

**I have tried calling bought successfully component separately and it works fine, the problem arises when it is being called after the transaction pending component.**

Comment: Why are you using the angular-material tag? It looks like you are using materializecss not Angular Material.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that first time in pending state you've created the component and declared his modal status on ngOnInit.
second time in success state you did the same, but the modal from the first component still active.
Try to implement OnDestroy interface and the method ngOnDestroy to close the modal.